# Get DropDownList Selected Value by Selected Text

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

Do anyone knows how to get selected value of a drop down list by selected text?

I tried the below method but doesn't work:

```
ddlWorkType.SelectedItem.Text = "writing"
myddlvalue = ddlWorkType.SelectedValue
```

Please show me how. Thanks.

Comment: check this link, may be helpful for you.[link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379579/how-to-getvalue-from-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 11):

```
 DDLResp.Items.FindByText(TxtResp.Text.Trim).Selected = True
```

Try this Code

Comment: Please explain what this code does and how it solves the problem. Kindly edit your answer instead of posting a comment.

Comment: The above sets the ddl selection with text ***TxtResp.Text*** to ***Selected***. By modifying the code I use the code `myddlvalue  = ddlWorkType.Items.FindByText(lblWorkType.Text.Trim).Value` to find drop down list value.

Answer (score 2):

how to get selected value and selected text in vb.net

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="textbox" ID="ddlUser"  runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">Select User</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><br />
```

Selected DropDownList value

```
ddlvalue = ddlUser.SelectedItem.Value
```

Selected DropDownList text

```
ddlText = ddlUser.SelectedItem.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Selected text is actually text which you selecting through mouse drag or by press shift key to copy/paste or delete text. You need to use just `.Text` instead of `.SelectedText`

```
ddlWorkType.Text = "writing"
myddlvalue = ddlWorkType.SelectedValue
```

if the text does not exist in assign datasource then combobox SelectedIndex will return -1 and SelectedValue will return Nothing.